# Replace values for specific rows from another row using a condition

Tags: r

```
1)PatientID 2)Review_year 3)CurrentHealthstate  4)Healthstateprevious   

1   2005    2   NA
2   2006    3   NA
3   2007    3   NA
4   2008    3   NA
5   2009    3   NA
6   2010    3   NA
7   2011    3   NA
8   2012    3   NA
9   2013    3   NA
```

I want to understand how to I can replace the NA values in the `4)Healthstateprevious` with the values of the `3)CurrentHealthstate` in the previous `2)Review_year`.

eg.

```
1   2005    2   NIL
2   2006    4   2
3   2007    3   4
4   2008    2   3
5   2009    1   2
6   2010    3   1
7   2011    4   3
8   2012    5   4
9   2013    3   5
```

Comment: 1)PatientID 2)Review_year 3)CurrentHealthstate 4)Healthstateprevious 
    
1 2005 2 NA
2 2006 3 NA
3 2007 3 NA
4 2008 3 NA
5 2009 3 NA
6 2010 3 NA
7 2011 3 NA
8 2012 3 NA
9 2013 3 NA

I want to understand how to I can replace the NA values in the 4)Healthstateprevious with the values of the 3)CurrentHealthstate in the previous 2)Review_year. 

eg.

1 2005 2 NIL
2 2006 4 2
3 2007 3 4
4 2008 2 3
5 2009 1 2
6 2010 3 1
7 2011 4 3
8 2012 5 4
9 2013 3 5

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I failed to mentioned that the ID number is unique and there are in many cases many the same ID number for different health states. How do I add an 'anchor so the patient ID coincides with the review year? eg.

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- read.table(text = "1   2005    2   NIL
2   2006    4   2
3   2007    3   4
4   2008    2   3
5   2009    1   2
6   2010    3   1
7   2011    4   3
8   2012    5   4
9   2013    3   5")

df %>% 
  mutate(newvar = lag(V3, 1))

  V1   V2 V3  V4 newvar
1  1 2005  2 NIL     NA
2  2 2006  4   2      2
3  3 2007  3   4      4
4  4 2008  2   3      3
5  5 2009  1   2      2
6  6 2010  3   1      1
7  7 2011  4   3      3
8  8 2012  5   4      4
9  9 2013  3   5      5
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to achieve this is to use subsetting:

```
data$Healthstateprevious[-1] <- data$CurrentHealthstate[-ncol(data)]
data
  PatientID Review_year CurrentHealthstate Healthstateprevious
1         1        2005                  2                  NA
2         2        2006                  4                   2
3         3        2007                  3                   4
4         4        2008                  2                   3
5         5        2009                  1                   1
6         6        2010                  3                   3
7         7        2011                  4                   4
8         8        2012                  5                   5
9         9        2013                  3                   3
```

data:

```
data <- data.frame(
  PatientID           = 1:9, 
  Review_year         = 2005:2013, 
  CurrentHealthstate  = c(2, 4, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 3), 
  Healthstateprevious = NA
)
```

Comment: This simply removes the first column of the variables and continues to complete the remainder using the health state of that very year and not the previous?